# Should I use the "self" version of a variable every time within a Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is more of a question of what are the best practices or best style tips on using `self` in Python than how to use it. Basically my question is, should I use the "self" version of my variable as soon as possible and every time after that, or is it appropriate to use the "non-self" version sometimes.

Here is an example where I use the "self" version of my variables as soon as possible:

```
def outside_function1(var1, var2):
    """Does something"""
    
def outside_function2(var1, var2):
    """Does something else"""

class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        
        self.variable_to_calculate = outside_function1(self.a, self.b, self.c) + outside_fuction2(self.a, self.b, self.d)
```

Here is a different example where I don't use the "self" version of my variables within the same init function:

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        
        self.variable_to_calculate = outside_function1(a, b, c) + outside_fuction2(a, b, d)
```

In case you didn't catch it, the difference is on the line with `self.variable_to_calculate`.

My thought is that the second example, where I don't use `self` every time, is maybe more readable. It keeps you from having to scroll over to the right to read the whole line. I also think it makes it quicker to tell which variables are being passed into the outside functions. But I could also see cases where there would maybe be more clarity using the first example.

So if both of these examples would do the exact same thing, is one of them more correct?

Comment: If you want the variable to be easily reachable for other methods of the class use self. If its not the case you can of course use the initial variable in your init method.

Comment: In your example there is a subtle difference. If one of those variables was a property with a getter and a setter, `a` and `self.a` may be different - or at least getter code wasn't run. That's completely depending on the class implementation which you should already know about, so no big deal - unless its changed in the future. There are some operations that won't work right. `a += 1` may not update `self.a`. But other than that, either option is okay.

Comment: An additional convention is to declare (for example) `a` as `self._a` (leading underscore) if the variable is designed to be 'private' to the class, or in other words not designed to be accessed by anything outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

In *this* case, the parameters you provide to `__init__` are for the constructor, presumably meaning they're directly related to the object itself and may be used in the future. If this is the case then `self` is important and needed.

If they're just temporary, maybe only used once or for setting something else up, then you should be totally fine with using the non-`self` variant. I agree it helps with readability and theres no need for `self` if you're not storing them more permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use the self variant as soon as possible. The reason for this is maintainability. The parameters of the init function are only used to feed the constructor.

Let's say in the future you don't want to call outside_function anymore with var b directly, because your class was adapted and var b is now split in var e and var f. Internally, you can still recreate self.b and you wouldn't have to change any outside functions calls.